# Value returning Null but state is correct

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a bit of confusion here. I have a parent component that is subscribing and getting data (I am using redux dev tool and I am monitoring it and it is updating the state when needed). In component A I am doing:

```
public FDC$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getFDC));
```

Next in the template for the parent component I am sending FDC$ to a child component like so:

```
  <app-order-list [fdc]= "(FDC$ | async)"></app-order-list>
```

In the child component I have fdc as an input.

When I try to console.log the fdc it returns null but in the redux dev tools it is showing the correct state. It seems as if the data is not being sent from parent to child.

Edit: Adding selector

Root:

```
export const getCurrent= (state: State) => state.current;

export const getFDC= createSelector(current, state => state.FDC);
```

(In the root index I call current so I can just do fromRoot.getFDC)

Comment: Can you show reducer code ?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake on my behalf, the state was not being updated before the NgOnInit of the child component so the value was coming back null. I ended up implemented NgOnChange and it works just fine now. Thanks all